# Kobold2d 2.0.4 SpaceManager library not updated

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am trying to use the spaceManager library but It won't even compile with the spaceManager 1.3. According to MobileBros the creator of spaceManager I need to update the spaceManager library because version 1.3 is not compatible with cocos2d 2.0. So I am just wondering how to go about doing that? I have already downloaded the latest version of SpaceManager so I just needed to know what the best way is to go about updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in spacemanager in Kobold2D 2.0.4 should work, it just doesn't rotate sprites.

If the new spacemanager version uses the exact same filenames (no new, removed or renamed files) you can just replace the existing spacemanager files with the newer version.

If not, you may have to add/remove the corresponding files to and from the Xcode project, specifically the chipmunk-spacemanager targets in the Kobold2D-Libraries project.

I'll include spacemanager 0.2 in the next release.